# When trying to run rspec, I get "uninitialized constant ActiveModel"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, guard

When I run `rspec spec` I get the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0/lib/rspec/rails/extensions/active_record/base.rb:26:in `': uninitialized constant ActiveModel (NameError)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0/lib/rspec/rails/extensions.rb:1:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0/lib/rspec/rails/extensions.rb:1:in `'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0/lib/rspec/rails.rb:8:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.7.0/lib/rspec/rails.rb:8:in `'
    from /Users/noahc/Dropbox/perfect_setup/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `require'
    from /Users/noahc/Dropbox/perfect_setup/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `'
    from /Users/noahc/Dropbox/perfect_setup/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/noahc/Dropbox/perfect_setup/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `map'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:459:in `load_spec_files'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run_in_process'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

My spec_helper.rb looks like this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.fixture_path = "#{Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  load "#{Rails.root}/config/routes.rb"
  Dir["#{Rails.root}/app/**/*.rb"].each {|f| load f}
end

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_with :rspec
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
end

Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each{|f| require f}
```

If I delete my pages_controller_spec file the errors go away. But I have zero specs to run.

The error returns when I have something even as simple as this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe PagesController do
  it "should do something..."
end
```

Also, if I add any tests no matter where I get the same error.

Any clues on other things I can try?

Comment: Have you tried `bundle exec guard start`?

Comment: @topek that resulted in the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you running `rspec spec`? The typical thing to run is `rake spec`.

Try `bundle exec rspec spec` or `bundle exec rake spec`.

If that doesn't work, try to see if something is wrong with the rest of your environment -- try `bundle exec rails console` and `bundle exec rails server`

Another thing to check, is there anything odd in **.rspec** in your project file, or **~/.rspec**?

Comment: I reset up the whole rails project in a new project and that fixed it. The 'rspec spec' came from the Rails Tutorial by MH.

Comment: is this issue related to this question here: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5449368;jsessionid=25862B8EFA5E5EA3A4ABEB91FDB69473 ?

Comment: I am encountering this same issue. @NoahClark, what exactly do you mean by "i reset up the whole rails project in a new project? Did you create a new project and just transfer the files one by one until it was working?

Comment: @Zyren yeah, that's probably what I did not sure as it's been a couple years. Might want to check your models as that seems to be the issue.

Comment: I figured out what it is. I had a duplicate line in my spec_helper from copying/pasting stuff into it and it caused that error.

Answer (score 3):

Found this thread while debugging the same symptoms. Here is another reason for the error: I had run

```
rspec --init
```

but had failed to run

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

Doing the latter fixed the problem.

Comment: Same here, I had run rspec --init, but not rails generate rspec:install. The Rails generator includes Rails.root in the spec helper.

Answer (score 2):

In my case

```
  gem "spork-rails", "~> 4.0.0"
```

was missing in `./Gemfile`.

Comment: Also you **must** add `  gem 'spork', '~> 1.0.0rc4'` to your gemfile regardless of what SporkRails says. SporkRails will **not** find it by itself.