# Why won't my rails spec run?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I try to run my spec, I get an uninitialized constant error. My spec looks like this:

```
describe Facility do 
  it { should have_many(:units) }
  it { should have_many(:facilities_users) }
  it { should have_many(:administrators) }
  it { should have_many(:facility_employees) }
end
```

The error is:
`` facility_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Facility (NameError) ``

I certainly have a Facility model, so I'm not sure why this would happen.

Comment: Are you running 'rspec spec' command ? And which rails version? Can you add the line where you add rspec to your Gemfile ?

Comment: @Danpe Whoops...Thanks. I was just doing ```rspec```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try running `rake spec` instead of `rspec spec`.
But both may work.

If not working try Try `bundle exec rspec spec` or `bundle exec rake spec`.

*Source: [When trying to run rspec I get uninitialized constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055040/when-trying-to-run-rspec-i-get-uninitialized-constant-activemodel).*

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the top of your file:

```
require 'spec_helper'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the 'rspec-rails' gem, then run

`rails g rspec:install`

This will create the `spec/spec_helper.rb` file (you should edit it if you're not using ActiveRecord so it runs you spec setup correctly).

After that, ensure you are requiring the helper at the top of your spec files:

`require 'spec_helper'`

If this didn't work for you, there might be more issues like:

1. You're trying to test a file under the lib/ directory. In this case,
   make sure this file is loaded with the environment
   (config/application.rb -> autoload_paths) or require it explicitly.
2. The constant actually doesn't exist. It could be inside a namespace or just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

In the spec file, require the file where `Facility` class is defined.