# Why won't my features specs run in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In my Rails 4 app, I'm using Rspec for testing. My directory structure is

```
spec
-- controllers
-- factories
-- features
-- spec_helper.rb
-- support
```

When I run `rspec spec`, it runs my tests in `controllers`, but not in `features`. I can specify `rspec spec/features` and they'll run, but I want to be able to run all tests under `spec` at once. My guess is it's not looking in `features` because of a configuration setting, but I don't know where this is.

I've tried different [incantations of starting rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958985/why-wont-my-rails-spec-run) but haven't had any luck.

Comment: What are the files called in the features folder?

Comment: `user_views_homepage.rb`, for example. Oh, I see now, needs a `_spec.rb` ending. I feel dumb for missing that--thank you.

Comment: What fooled me is that you said the tests run if you specify `spec/features`.  Is that really true?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin sorry, that was bad information on my part, if I specified the file, it worked, like `rspec spec/features/user_views_homepage.rb`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on your feedback to the comments above, the issue is one of file naming.  I've definitely been burned by that before too.  By default Rspec will go through the files looking for ones ending with `_spec.rb`, this default behaviour is overridden if you specify the folder manually.

Comment: Specifying a containing folder does not override that behavior.